# Turn mod_rewrite rules into PHP rules

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to handle mod rewrites from within PHP instead of my .htaccess file, this way when I have custom modules that need a new rewrite I don't have to redo the .htaccess file.

I want to mimic the way that WordPress does their .htaccess which is:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My current .htaccess is this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# MBP Rules
RewriteRule ^module/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=$1&module_page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^module/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=$1&module_page=$2&page=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^module/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=module&prefix=$1&module_page=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-_]+)/([A-Za-z-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&s=$2&id=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Comment: just keep in mind that Apache's rewrites run/happen BEFORE any PHP is invoked. Unless you're going to dynamically `include` sub pages and the like, at best you'll have to do a full-blown http 301/302 redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way is to replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

With

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then you have to do similar parsing and everything as modrewrite does, but you can do it yourself using preg_match on $_GET['path'].  I.e.

```
if (preg_match('/id/([0-9]*)', $_GET['path'], $matches)) {
    Do code;
}
```

Comment: Argh, this site needs an android friendly editor.  I don't know how to put code blocks in on my phone

Comment: Select the text and press the code button in the toolbar. I'll do it for you. Good job on writing all that from your android though, +1 to that

Comment: And half my stuff is posted from my phone :)

Comment: That's weird, I'm using android (sometimes) and I do see the buttons.

Comment: Just did a save page, I see the button bar div, but it's empty.  Should I post on Meta?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, have the `.htaccess` file look like the first example you have, and build your script from there.

Probably write some sort of `Router` class, to route the requests to their places, the fundamentals being splitting the received query by `/`, which gives you an array of URL parts, and start conditioning.